# Is there a term for French words adopted by the English language, such as "hors d'oeuvres" or "objet d'art"

Tags: phrases, terminology, loanwords, neologisms

I would call them "Frenchisms" or some such -ism, but I figured I'd at least ask first. So is there a name for such adopted foreign phrases? Also, how about those adopted from languages other than French? Same deal?

I know neologisms are new terms or phrases that have yet to be made official, but that's not so relevant here, since these adopted phrases aren't exactly new.

Comment: You're probably talking about half the dictionary!

Comment: @IainMH: [you're not that far off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Origins_of_English_PieChart.svg).

Comment: How many of those words have been slightly altered though? Probably most of them. I was thinking more about words that are clearly foreign in nature, and unaltered (as the examples above that I had posted). I hear what you're saying though! :)

Comment: *hors d'oeuvres* was altered, if only because it apparently lost its signature **œ**

Comment: *bon appétit* is another one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The term is *loan words*; I am not aware of any language-specific term other than *Latinate words*. *Loan* is a bit of a misnomer, though, for words that have become part of the English lexicon -- we're never giving them back.

Comment: Heh, gotta love permanent borrowing.

Comment: *loanword* (without hyphen) is also acceptable, and even seems to be the prefered spelling these days

Comment: It's not all one way, 'le parking', 'le weekend', 'le sandwich' the [Académie Française](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/03/academie-francaise/) don't like it but...

Answer (score 7):

If there are circumstances in which you want an alternative to *French loan word*, I suggest *gallicism*.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with @bye's assertion of 'loan words'. Many are of French origin, but quite a few are borrowed from languages from the Indian subcontinent and reflect the period of British Rule.

These include: Shampoo, Pyjama, jodhpurs, Calico, Doolally and [many, many others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Hindi_or_Urdu_origin). 
 -